# Directive to ignore compilation of an element

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I wanna write a directive called `ng-ignore` to prevent the HTML compiler from processing an element and it's children.

I've been practicing writing directives, but a bit confused about this one.

---

I want something like this:

```
angular.module("myMod", [])
.directive("ngIgnore", function()
{
    var dirDefObj = {
        // What should I write here to have compiler ignore this element?
    };
    return dirDefObj;
});
```

to be used like this:

```
<div ng-ignore>
    This div must be ignored by Angular's compiler.
</div>
```

Need help and pointers for writing it. Thanks.

Comment: a use case and example would help

Comment: update isn't very informative

Comment: Why would you want this? To write `{{bla}}` without it being a variable? Simple: `&#123;&#123;bla&#125;&#125;`

Comment: What would be the difference between this and `ngIf`?

Comment: @mb21 I wanted it because I am writing a web page that uses angular to document an angular module. My code sample has {{foo}} in it, and it needs to be ignored.

Answer (score 5):

Angular already has this built in [ngNonBindable](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngNonBindable)

```
<div>Normal: {{1 + 2}}</div>
<div ng-non-bindable>Ignored: {{1 + 2}}</div>
```

Normal: 3

Ignored: {{1 + 2}}

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Ygyb4KqjeAgIWNUqaRbw?p=preview)

Comment: Tested it, but doesn't seem to be what I'm after. I wanna use the ignored DOM subtree `angular.bootstrap`ed with another `angular.module`, where in either case I'm getting `App Already Bootstrapped with this Element`. Though, thanks for this answer already!